# Multiple login in one browser

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, cookies

Assume that I have two accounts in a site.[for example in stackoverflow]. is there any way to login with both in two tabs of one browser?

In normal state, when I login in one tab, automatically the other tab will log in.

Comment: you can use different url with 2 set of cookies to define the login details

Comment: you can be inspired by Gmail multiple login feature

Comment: Typically the sessions are identified using cookies. So if you are somehow able to make browser use different cookies in different tabs for the same website, you should get your job done. For eg: in Chrome, its possible if you opened another tab in incognito mode.

Oh and BTW, as this question stands, it is off-topic.

Comment: @MaveRick would you please explain more simple? I use gmail multiple login before, but I don't know how use/add this feature for other sites.

Comment: @Thrustmaster yes, you right. but how?! and for the incognitov,as I know we can not have an incognitov tab and an a normal tab in a single windows.

Comment: You can use CentBrowser. Just Ctrl + M.
https://www.centbrowser.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Firefox

In Firefox, you can have separate sessions with the [Multifox extension](https://getmultifox.com/). Unfortunately, it requires sessions be in separate windows instead of separate tabs.

The same developer is working on a new extension [AllAccounts](https://getmultifox.com/allaccounts/) which is still in beta, but does support multiple sessions in the same window.

### Chrome

For Chrome, there is an extension called [MultiLogin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilogin/ijfgglilaeakmoilplpcjcgjaoleopfi?hl=en), which gives support for different sessions in each tab. Note that it is *only free for personal use*, so if you are using it at work, you may have to email the developer to inquire about a commercial license.

### Internet Explorer

As far as I know, there is no extension for Internet Explorer that allows for multiple sessions in the same window. But for IE10, to get a new session in a new window, press <kbd>alt</kbd> to open the menu bar, then click `File->New session`.

### Testing

To test multiple sessions, you can try using the very handy [IE browser session test page](http://www.enhanceie.com/test/sessions/). You can set the background color of the page, then open it again in a new session and you should be able to set a different background. It also displays what sessions are being stored in the browser's sessionStorage and localStorage.

These are the results from my testing with Firefox 36, Chrome 41 and IE 10:

- [Multifox](https://getmultifox.com/) v3.1.0: Each session has separate sessionStorage and localStorage
- [AllAccounts](https://getmultifox.com/allaccounts/) v2.1alpha3: Each session has separate sessionStorage and localStorage
- [MultiLogin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilogin/ijfgglilaeakmoilplpcjcgjaoleopfi?hl=en) v0.1620: Each session has separate sessionStorage *but shares localStorage*
- IE 10: Each session has separate sessionStorage and localStorage

Answer (score 2):

Set your web browser to block cookies for the site. It will prevent auto-login when the tab closes but, for many sites, that won't prevent you from logging in.

Answer (score 2):

## Chrome Browser:

You can use [MultiLogin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilogin/ijfgglilaeakmoilplpcjcgjaoleopfi?hl=en) as suggested in other answer or to create multiple login screens in different tabs within same Chrome window you can use other extension, it's really good and I'm using it: [SessionBox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sessionbox-beta/megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solve this by using the incognito-mode in Chrome.

In the normal window, I am signed in with my usual (personal) account. In the incognito-window I am using the other account.

I tested this with Amazon and Airbrake.

DISCLAIMER:

Strictly speaking, I have two instances of the same browser, not two tabs. But at least for me it's "close enough".

Comment: Yes, I tested this before. but I want multiple login in one window and different tabs. I want to login with 3 accounts at least. thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

The fastest most convenient way that I can think of using multiple browser tabs with different sessions without installing any external software is through using a proxy website.

I use "https://proxysite.com/" for work.

Disclaimer that using a third-party service like this, while convenient, is not very secure, so do not use for sensitive transactions involving things like banking or credit card info.